# Get data from JSON with ng-repeat | Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a tiny problem here and I don't know how to solve it..

I want to get the `description`s from this JSON:

```
    { story:
   [ { description: 'Paketet är påväg.',
       icon: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/parceltrace.png' },
     { date: '2016-08-26T10:21:02+02:00',
       icon: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/parceltrace.png',
       description: 'Paketet är redo för upphämtning.' },
     { date: '2016-08-25T11:15:11+02:00',
       icon: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png',
       description: 'Paketet har hanterats i terminal.' },
     { date: '2016-08-25T09:08:59+02:00',
       icon: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png',
       description: 'Paketet har hanterats i terminal.' },
     { date: '2016-08-24T12:35:36+02:00',
       icon: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png',
       description: 'Paketet har hanterats i terminal.' },
     { date: '2016-08-24T12:19:29+02:00',
       icon: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png',
       description: 'Paketet har hanterats i terminal.' } ],
  data:
   { height: '12 cm',
     width: '16 cm',
     depth: '20 cm',
     weight: '0 kg' } }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="ul-card" ng-repeat="item in story.description">
    <li>
        <i class="right-text fa fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>
        <p class="left-text">{{item.description}}</p>
        <p class="left-text subtitle">26 jun 2017 16:32</p>
        <p class="left-text">Leveransen har blivit levererad</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### My Logic:

In my `ul` tag I've put a `ng-repeat` directive to loop trough all the descriptions in my story object (if I'm correct). I then get the description from `item` with my `{{item.description}}` expression. But nothing is getting outputted even the DOM element is getting deleted.

So I'm pretty stuck here and I'd like some help. I am really grateful for all the help I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to store your data coming from your API in the $scope like this:

```
$scope.myApiData = { story: [ { description: ...
```

Instead of:

```
<ul class="ul-card" ng-repeat="item in story.description">
```

Do that:

```
<ul class="ul-card" ng-repeat="item in myApiData.story">
```

Comment: Hey! I tried that before and with no luck. Thanks for replying!

Comment: How do you store your big object in your scope? If you do something like this : `$scope.blah = { story: [ ... ] }` You need to use this syntax in your template : `ng-repeat="item in blah.story"`

Comment: Are you referring to the JSON?

Comment: My CTO said that this is all I will get from the API. So I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes but when you will receive this json data, you will need to store it in the `$scope` to bind it to your template. All you need to do is to choose a variable name (I chose `blah` for the example) to store your data is the new variable.

Comment: But can I just add a variable to `ng-repeat="item in blah.story"` without changing the JSON?

Comment: JSON is like object is JavaScript so you can store it in a variable of the $scope with the name you choose.

Comment: @MartinNordström When you want to make a *copy* of the JSON, use `$scope.myJson = angular.copy(JSON)`, you can now add anything you want to `$scope.myJson`, without changing the original JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is like this in your controller:

```
$scope.data = {
                "story": [
                    {
                        "description": "Paketet är påväg.",
                        "icon": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/parceltrace.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2016-08-26T10:21:02+02:00",
                        "icon": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/parceltrace.png",
                        "description": "Paketet är redo för upphämtning."
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2016-08-25T11:15:11+02:00",
                        "icon": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png",
                        "description": "Paketet har hanterats i terminal."
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2016-08-25T09:08:59+02:00",
                        "icon": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png",
                        "description": "Paketet har hanterats i terminal."
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2016-08-24T12:35:36+02:00",
                        "icon": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png",
                        "description": "Paketet har hanterats i terminal."
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2016-08-24T12:19:29+02:00",
                        "icon": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qlocx-bilder/public/checkbox.png",
                        "description": "Paketet har hanterats i terminal."
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                    "height": "12 cm",
                    "width": "16 cm",
                    "depth": "20 cm",
                    "weight": "0 kg"
                }
            };
```

In your html, you should do like this:

```
<ul class="ul-card" ng-repeat="item in data.story">
    <li>
        <i class="right-text fa fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>
        <p class="left-text">{{item.description}}</p>
        <p class="left-text subtitle">26 jun 2017 16:32</p>
        <p class="left-text">Leveransen har blivit levererad</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My CTO said that this is all I will get from the API. So I'm not sure if I should have something before `story`.

Comment: You can log what the APi returns and adapt the code depending that.